# how to deploy java web application on tomcat without displaying 8080 port?

Tags: apache, tomcat

I want to deploy java web application on 8080 port of tomcat server but i want that URL does not contain port no with domain name.

I can't change the port from 8080 to 80 because i have some other application running on different server with port 80.

Comment: The reason your browser shows you the port is because by default, HTTP port is 80 and is omitted. If you were not to specify the port, your browser would not know where to request from.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an alias [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Host_Name_Aliases) go to Host Name Aliases and configure your name of choice. This way you can skip localhost:port/path/to/project and just have project_name.loc or whatever you come up with.